# After login, how to send user back to the same portal page that they were on before loging in?

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

im using websphere portal 6.1.5 and portlet factory 7

How can i send user to a custom page intead of portal home page if user accecces a certain page before loging in?

i want to return the user to the same page that they were on before they clicked login link and went to login page. any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No WebSphere by default redirects the user to the first page that he has access to right after login. In order to make portal redirect the user to a custom page you would have to implement a LoginFilter; which can be attached to the wps.war.

Take a look at:

[Info Center: Configuring authentication filters](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v6101/admin/adauthflt.html)

[Creating loginfilter for WebSphere Portal](http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2009/12/creating-loginfilter-for-websphere.html)

[TechNote: New security APIs in WebSphere Portal](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0905_buchwald/0905_buchwald.html)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

That should be the default behaviour. If the user is redirected to the login page after login the WAS Server woudl redirect you back to that particular page.

This assumes that the URL is unique for that page because that is what is stored by the server before it does the re-direct to the login page.

Cheers
Manglu

Comment: Thanks for the answers. i used /wps/portal/.... in my url earlier. I changes that to /wps/myportal/... and that caused the login page to be called and afterwards i was returned to the required page. I did need to pass some argument too which i did with render params.

Answer (score 0):

The default Login redirect behaviour is true, but only if the Login page is requested using the unprotected URL.
If the page is available within the protected area, meaning for authenticated users as well you can change the calculation of the redirect behaviour even without a loginfilter.
Therefore you would need to send a redirect to the current page but reference the protected area. Like wps/portal/a/b/c is the URL the user is currently visiting the login link should trigger wps/myportal/a/b/c. 
WebSphere will kick in and require authentication for the user, but stores the original requested URL. This information is then reused from Portal after the user authenticated